# Why can't i properly link opengl libraries? (Windows, mingw, command line)

Tags: c++, opengl, mingw, static-libraries, static-linking

So basically what i am trying to do, is setting up opengl on a windows pc without VS. This is a pain, since every damn tutorial on this planet uses Visual Studio, but i simply hate it so i will not use it.
What i did was downloading all the necessary libraries, setting up a project, creating a main file and than a Makefile.
main.cpp:

```cpp
#define FREEGLUT_STATIC
#include <windows.h>
#include <GL/glut.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv){
    glutInit(&argc,argv);
    glutCreateWindow("hello");
    glutInitWindowSize(400,400);
    glutMainLoop();
    return 0;
}
```

My Makefile:

```
INCL_DIR = include
SRC_DIR = src
LIB_DIR = lib
BUILD_DIR = build
OUTPUT_NAME = graph.exe

CXX = g++
CXXFLAGS = -I$(INCL_DIR) 
LDFLAGS = -L$(LIB_DIR) -lfreeglut -lglew32 -lopengl32 -lgdi32 -lwinmm

SRCS := $(wildcard $(SRC_DIR)/*.cpp)
OBJS := $(SRCS:%.cpp=%.o)

$(OUTPUT_NAME): $(OBJS)
    $(CXX) -o $(BUILD_DIR)/$(OUTPUT_NAME) $(OBJS) $(CXXFLAGS)

clean:
    del /f $(SRC_DIR)\*.o
    del /f $(BUILD_DIR)\$(OUTPUT_NAME)
```

The project hierarchy:
[image: Picture of the project hierarchy in VSCode]

What happens when i run make:

```sh
PS C:\programming\projects\opengl_base> make
g++ -Iinclude    -c -o src/main.o src/main.cpp
g++ -o build/graph.exe src/main.o -Iinclude 
src/main.o:main.cpp:(.text+0x23): undefined reference to `__glutInitWithExit'
src/main.o:main.cpp:(.text+0x46): undefined reference to `__glutCreateWindowWithExit'
src/main.o:main.cpp:(.text+0x68): undefined reference to `__glutCreateMenuWithExit'
src/main.o:main.cpp:(.text+0xad): undefined reference to `glutInitWindowSize'
src/main.o:main.cpp:(.text+0xb2): undefined reference to `glutMainLoop'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [graph.exe] Error 1
```

What i understand is, that the libraries simply don't get linked for some reason. But why? Please help me

Comment: Firstly, `-L...` and `-l...` don't belong in `CXXFLAGS`, and are silently ignored when compiling (but not when linkling). Normally you have a separate variable called `LDFLAGS`, used in place of `CXXFLAGS` when linking. Next, googling reveals that `__imp_timeBeginPeriod` is from "winmm" library, so add `-lwinmm`. Next, `__imp_glPushAttrib` is from `-lopengl32` (since you already have it, it's probably positioned incorrectly relative to other `-l...` flags, try moving it to the end).

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Thanks for the answer. I have edited everything as you have said and it looks much better. Now im at a state i have reached when trying to manipulate someone other's CLion project. (At least now i'm proud i have reached this from scratch)

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Nvm i'm stupid i didn't update the Makefile correctly. Now it compiles and runs. THANK YOU

Answer (score 1):

So to anyone who stumbles upon this question later on: whenever you try to link more libraries, and they depend on eachother, mess a little bit with the order of them.

Comment: Yes, the order on which you specify them to the linker matters. Back in the "old" days you sometimes even had to put them on the linker line several times. Try switching to LLVM's `lld` or the GNU `gold` linker.

Answer (score 1):

Your line to link the exe file has compiler flags instead of linker flags init.
To fix this in `Makefile` change:

```
        $(CXX) -o $(BUILD_DIR)/$(OUTPUT_NAME) $(OBJS) $(CXXFLAGS)
```

to:

```
        $(CXX) -o $(BUILD_DIR)/$(OUTPUT_NAME) $(OBJS) $(LDFLAGS)
```